# SQL query to find the depending index of a column

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

if a table has an index created for its column 'col', altering the column will give something like "The index 'index1' is dependent on column 'col'."

Given a table name and a column name, how do you write a SQL query to list out the depending indexes for that column?

Database is MSSQL2008R2

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply query the meta data:

```
SELECT  IndexName = i.Name
FROM    [sys].[index_columns] ic
        INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] c
            ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
            AND ic.[column_id] = c.[column_id]          
        INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] i
            ON i.[object_id] = ic.[object_id]
            AND i.[index_id] = ic.[index_id]
WHERE   ic.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName')
AND     c.Name = 'ColumnName';
```